# Is this the correct approach to achieve concurrency?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, reentrantlock

I have created a small application which basically includes rest Apis for money transfer between accounts. For the simplicity I have used concurrent hashmap for datastore. Now the very basic concept to be implemented for this would be multi threading.

As I am not using any DB, I have created lock on the Account class itself using reentrant lock. Now when I am doing the transaction I am obtaining the lock on both the account objects i.e. sender and receiver and then passing it to a biconsumer.accept().

I am not sure if this is entirely correct (in terms of this app only.).
Also not sure how to do unit testing for this.

Account.java

```
public class Account {

    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private String accountNumber;
    private long accountBalance;

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public long getAccountBalance() {
        return accountBalance;
    }

    public void setAccountBalance(long accountBalance) {
        this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
    }

    public void getLock() {
        this.accountLock.lock();
    }

    public void doUnlock() {
        this.accountLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Transfer.java

```
send(senderAccount, receiverAccount, (x, y) -> {
                    senderAccount.setAccountBalance(senderAccount.getAccountBalance() - (transferAmount));
                    receiverAccount.setAccountBalance(toAccountDto.getAccountBalance() + transferAmount));
                });


public void send(Account senderAccount, Account receiverAccount,
            BiConsumer<Account, Account> action) {
        senderAccount.lock();
        try {
            receiverAccount.lock();
            try {
                biConsumer.accept(senderAccount, receiverAccount);
            } finally {
                receiverAccount.unlock();
            }
        } finally {
            senderAccount.unlock();
        }
    }
```

In terms of single thread this works just fine as expected.
But how can I unit test this to check if it works fine with 10000 threads.

Also is this account level locking a good practice (in terms of this app), or I could have done something else ?

Comment: You can take help of : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: Ok. That would be for testing purpose. But is this the correct if I do locking like this ?

Comment: You can have a deadlock if two accounts send money to each other.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I think if I use tryLock(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS); this should solve the issue. RIght ?

Comment: hen you have to check the return value too. Locks are a can of worms. And what should you do when the first lock succeeds and the second one fails? Unlock the first one? Wait? How long? (some random time is probably the best answer). Your system will soon be so complex that it will be hard to reason about it.

Answer (score 1):

Locks are a bad tool for this.

In the example you posted, there is a possibility that there will be a deadlock if two threads send money between two accounts.

```
final Account acc1 = new Account();
final Account acc2 = new Account();
new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        send(acc1, acc2, (x, y) -> {
            x.setAccountBalance(x.getAccountBalance() - 100);
            y.setAccountBalance(y.getAccountBalance() + 100);
        }); 
    }
}).start();
new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        send(acc2, acc1, (x, y) -> {
            x.setAccountBalance(x.getAccountBalance() - 100);
            y.setAccountBalance(y.getAccountBalance() + 100);
        }); 
    }
}).start();
```

At some point Thread 1 will have a lock on `acc1` while Thread 2 holds the lock on `acc2`.

The usual way to prevent that is to have a certain order in which locks are acquired.
In this case, there are too many locks to manage that.

A better solution is to use an [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html), but that requires some changes in the code.

```
public class Account {

    private String accountNumber;
    private AtomicLong accountBalance = new AtomicLong();

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public long getAccountBalance() {
        return accountBalance.get();
    }

    /* Don't use this method if you expect that the balance has not changed since the last get */
    public void setAccountBalance(long accountBalance) {
        this.accountBalance.set(accountBalance);
    }

    /* Changes the balance atomically */
    public void addAccountBalance(long amountToAdd) {
        accountBalance.addAndGet(amountToAdd);
    }   
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
senderAccount.addAccountBalance(-sendAmount);
receiverAccount.addAccountBalance(sendAmount);
```

Because there are no locks, no deadlocks can occur.
And while each action is atomic, there are a few caveats:

- If you expect the old value to be some number, e.g. bigger than the transfer amount,
  you might have to use `compareAndSet` in a loop instead.
- If you need to guarantee that the sum of all accounts is constant at all times this method might fail (e.g. removed the money from one account, did not yet add it to an other account) - in that case, you need one big lock. But that would defeat concurrency, right?

The biggest problem when writing multithreaded code is to find out what guarantees you want to give - or what is still a consistent state. And then make sure no thread sees the system in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer. Can you please check the one I posted ? Can we resolve the issue like that by fixing the order or locks ?